# How to slid left/right two divs using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am new to coding and I am trying to achieve the following using JQuery:

I have two Divs Where clicking on the first shows some content and clicking the second would hide the content of the first one and show its content instead (Toggling). What I want to do is that I want to keep the same functionality but I want the second Div to slide to the right when I click on the first Div and make a drawer shape and vice versa. I have attached images to it so it may explain more about my idea.
both of contents are hidden by default.
I can't seem to know how to join these two functionalities together

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Test</title>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"
      integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="box-container">
      <div id="div1">
        <h1>Title one</h1>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Inventore
          quidem ex tenetur ipsum dolore repudiandae molestiae mollitia! Dolore
          numquam.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div id="div2">
        <h1>Title two</h1>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Inventore
          quidem ex tenetur ipsum dolore repudiandae molestiae mollitia! Dolore
          numquam.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="contentDiv1">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla voluptatem
      veritatis assumenda. Obcaecati veniam quo impedit tempora pariatur maiores
      ipsa voluptates commodi esse eveniet! Nihil corrupti illum at accusantium
      sit? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut veritatis
      et molestias? Reprehenderit distinctio sint provident ratione dolorem
      veritatis sapiente, fuga amet obcaecati. Laboriosam rerum consectetur nemo
      magnam saepe mollitia. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
      elit. Excepturi sit perferendis earum debitis corrupti dolore commodi
      minima consectetur veniam itaque inventore et pariatur sapiente, maxime
      quis, in nulla, eos molestias! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur,
      adipisicing elit. Quasi, incidunt repudiandae perferendis ea praesentium
      blanditiis, voluptate accusantium, repellat molestiae quisquam eveniet
      earum officia sed assumenda maxime officiis sequi laboriosam! Tempore.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias modi hic
      officia iste optio in delectus veniam obcaecati reprehenderit, voluptate
      ipsum! Incidunt ducimus animi, id quae blanditiis provident dignissimos
      harum?
    </div>
    <div id="contentDiv2">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla voluptatem
      veritatis assumenda. Obcaecati veniam quo impedit tempora pariatur maiores
      ipsa voluptates commodi esse eveniet! Nihil corrupti illum at accusantium
      sit? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut veritatis
      et molestias? Reprehenderit distinctio sint provident ratione dolorem
      veritatis sapiente, fuga amet obcaecati. Laboriosam rerum consectetur nemo
      magnam saepe mollitia. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
      elit. Excepturi sit perferendis earum debitis corrupti dolore commodi
      minima consectetur veniam itaque inventore et pariatur sapiente, maxime
      quis, in nulla, eos molestias! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur,
      adipisicing elit. Quasi, incidunt repudiandae perferendis ea praesentium
      blanditiis, voluptate accusantium, repellat molestiae quisquam eveniet
      earum officia sed assumenda maxime officiis sequi laboriosam! Tempore.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias modi hic
      officia iste optio in delectus veniam obcaecati reprehenderit, voluptate
      ipsum! Incidunt ducimus animi, id quae blanditiis provident dignissimos
      harum?
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 100px 100px 25px 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
#box-container {
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
}
#div1 {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #f57350, #fa8282);
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#div2 {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #a42e5a, #f57350);
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#contentDiv1,
#contetnDiv2 {
  margin: 25px;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#contentDiv1').hide();
    $('#contentDiv2').hide();
    
    $('#div1').on('click', function(){
        $('#contentDiv1').slideToggle();
        $('#contentDiv2').hide();       
    });
   
    $('#div2').on('click', function(){
        $('#contentDiv2').slideToggle();
        $('#contentDiv1').hide();
    });
});
```

[attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwdJj.jpg)

Comment: Please add your HTML code as well.

Comment: We are going to need more information then this like some css, html, the rest of your functions etc what would be perfect is a live example of what you have at the moment!

Comment: I added both the html and css

Answer (score 0):

It has more than one solution, and for me, this is my favorite method, I hope it helps you:

```js
$('.tabs .tab').on('click', function () {
  if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
    $(this).removeClass('active')
    .closest('.tabs').removeClass('active1 active2');
    $('.content').hide();
  } else {
    let i = $(this).index() + 1;
    $(this)
        .addClass('active')
        .siblings('.tab').removeClass('active')
        .closest('.tabs').removeClass('active1 active2')
        .addClass('active' + i);
    
    $('.content').hide();    
    $('.content' + i).fadeIn();
  }
});
```

```css
.tabs,
.tabs .tab,
.tabs .content {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.tabs {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
.tabs.active1 {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 65px;
}
.tabs.active2 {
    padding-left: 65px;
    padding-right: 0;
}
.tabs .tab {
    padding: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    min-width: 50%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.tabs.active1 .tab,
.tabs.active2 .tab {
    min-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.tabs .content {
    padding: 15px;
    min-width: 100%;
    display: none;
}
.tabs.active1 .tab1:not(.active),
.tabs.active2 .tab1:not(.active){
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    min-width: 65px;
    width: 65px;
}
.tabs.active1 .tab2:not(.active),
.tabs.active2 .tab2:not(.active) {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    min-width: 65px;
    width: 65px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs">
    <div class="tab tab1">div1</div>    
    <div class="tab tab2">div2</div>
    <div class="content content1">div content1</div>    
    <div class="content content2">div content2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot.. this is a great solution.. How can I get to the normal position using close button for example? I mean if i click on a button  in the content body to close it and get the two divs on the same line?

Comment: It has a solution
I will immediately modify the code

Comment: You are a life saver! I can't thank you enough! I will try applying it to me code

Comment: Hello Emy, hope you are doing well. I was wondering if it's possible to reach you personally. I need your help on a website i am working on. thank you